# How to Pass datatable as input to procedure in C#?

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0

I am wrote stored procedure to Insert data into database table but i am not getting how to pass datatable to stored procedure kindly tell how to use it.

### below is my storedprocedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_SREE_TEST(p_recordset In SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

Contrac_rc SREE_TEST%rowtype;
BEGIN

   Loop
   Fetch p_recordset Into Contrac_rc;
   EXIT WHEN p_recordset%NOTFOUND;
       Insert into SREE_TEST(CT,DESC,FLAG)
       Values(Contrac_rc.CT,Contrac_rc.DESC,Contrac_rc.FLAG);

   End Loop;


   EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END PR_SREE_TEST;
/
```

### and cs page

```
  public DataSet sreetest(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataSet dsRegularIndentdtl = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                OracleConnection OraConn = new OracleConnection(strDBConnection);
                OraConn.Open();

                OracleCommand OraCmd = new OracleCommand();
                OraCmd.Connection = OraConn;
                OraCmd.CommandText = "PR_SREE_TEST";
                OraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter();


                var recordSet1 = new DataTable();
                recordSet1 = dt;
               OraCmd.Parameters.Add("p_recordset", OracleDbType.RefCursor, recordSet1, ParameterDirection.Input);
                 OraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return dsRegularIndentdtl;
        }
    }
```

above is my code it is saying that p_recordset not valied. please tell me how to execute it.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547733/pass-datatable-from-c-sharp-to-oracle-stored-procedure

Comment: is it work for only single primary key only, if it is i have 4 primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct overload of OraCmd.Parameters.Add(),

As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t52t0485%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the fourth parameter is not parameter direction, it is as below

```
public OracleParameter Add(
    string parameterName,
    OracleType dataType,
    int size,
    string srcColumn
)
```

Comment: here i pass datatable to procedure so how to i write oraclepameter add()

Comment: Invalid parameter binding Parameter name: p_recordset error while executing procedure any suggestion

Comment: @vishali Why do you mark this as answer? Do you know how to pass a table in? If you have more detail, please let others know.

Comment: Vishali did the code work for you?. Please let me know, as I need to pass in a Datatable into an Oracle stored procedure.