# Insert Datatable into Oracle using OracleDataAdapter

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I need to insert specific rows from DataGridView into Oracle DB table. What I do is to set InsertCommand for OracleDataAdapter, create a new empty DataTable with same column names and fill OracleDataAdapter with It. Then I loop over rows in DataGridView, add desired rows to DataTable and then call da.Update() method - but It doesn't work, I get **"Value cannot be null. Parameter name:command"** error at same line - **da.Fill()**...This is my code as described:

```
private OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
private void Inicialize_adapter()
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string);
    conn.Open();

    OracleCommand insert = new OracleCommand("Myschema.InsertToTable", conn);

    insert.Parameters.Add("ID_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "ID");
    insert.Parameters.Add("ID_FK_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "ID_FK");
    insert.Parameters.Add("SERIAL_IN", OracleDbType.Decimal, 4, "SERIAL_NO");

    da.InsertCommand = insert;
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    conn.Close();
}
```

And code in my ButtonSave_Click:

```
...

Inicialize_adapter();

DataTable dt_Test = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int));
dt_Test.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("ID_FK", typeof(int));
dt_Test.Columns.Add(dc);

dc = new DataColumn("SERIAL_NO", typeof(int));
dt_Test.Columns.Add(dc);

var sequence = New_id(1); // this get's me next sequence in DB
int increase_seq = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MyDGV.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value == "Added")
    {
       DataRow newRow = dt_Test.NewRow();

       newRow[0] = sequence+increase_seq;
       newRow[1] = 2";
       newRow[2] = row.Cells[1].Value;

       dt_Test.Rows.Add(newRow.ItemArray);
       ++increase_seq;
     }
 }
 //Fill Adapter -error here
 da.Fill(dt_Test);

 da.Update(dt_Test);

  ...
```

I've tried also other options like Array Binding, but that didn't produce good results, so I wish I could get It working this way as It's simpler. Does anybody know what could be wrong in my code ? Thanks for help in advance !!

Comment: That's your insert command? "Myschema.InsertToTable"?

Comment: @RenatoAfonso, that is stored procedure in DB for insert into some related table, so yes. Is maybe that a conflict between DataAdapter.Fill() and Command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

First: To get the selected Rows from your DataGridView you could do that:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in MyDGV.Rows)
    {
        if (dr.Selected)
        {
            //Add to DataTable
        }
    }

    //Or even easier:

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MyDGV.SelectedRows)
    {
        //Add to DataTable
    }
```

The other part is the da.Fill()/da.Update(). I'm not sure if the "Myschema.InsertToTable" is a stored procedure (I haven't much experience with that) but I'am assuming it. So here are some ideas on how to insert a DataTable to an Oracle-Database with stored procedures: [OracleDataAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854542/how-to-insert-data-from-datatable-to-oracle-database-table)

So now I hope that I got it right and you can solve your problem (:

**Old answer:**

As far as I can tell this looks like you are trying to insert a DataRow with more Columns than you fill (Column-Name: command) and your DataBase doesn't accept null-value for that DataColumn. So you have eighter to change the DataBase to allow null-value on that Column or you give that column a value before insert it:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in MyDGV.Rows){
if (row.Cells[0].Value == "Added")
{
   DataRow newRow = dt_Test.NewRow();

   newRow[0] = sequence+increase_seq;
   newRow[1] = 2";
   newRow[2] = row.Cells[1].Value;
   newRow["command"] = "someValue";

   dt_Test.Rows.Add(newRow.ItemArray);
   ++increase_seq;
 }
```

}

Also have you tryed to use DataBinding? In my opinion this should make it all alot easier.

**Edit:**

OK then I got it wrong. Maybe you comand is wrong, but when we look at it with Databinding it should work. Here is a [Tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial)

What you Need is a DB-Connection, a DataAdapter and a DataSet and a BindingSource.

You already got the DataAdapter (OracleDataAdapter da) and the Connection (OracleConnection conn) but you don't use it correctly.

1. Initialise DB-Connection

   OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string);
2. Initialise DataAdapter

   string Query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable";
   OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(Query, conn);
3. Fill DataSet

   DataSet ds;
   da.Fill(ds, "Tablename");
4. Bind the Data to BindingSource

   BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Tablename");
5. Now you can populate the DataGridView

   DataGridView dgv;
   dgv.DataSource = bs;

After that you can work with the Data, edit them in the DataGridView etc. In the and you could generate the Insertcommands etc. and Update the Data (Changed Data, new Data, whatever you want).

```
bs.EndEdit();

OracleCommandBuilder ocb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
da.UpdateCommand = ocb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
da.InsertCommand = ocb.GetInsertCommand(true);
da.DeleteCommand = ocb.GetDeleteCommand(true);

da.Update(ds, "Tablename");
```

This is just a short overview, you need to look at it more detailed, i.e. it's important to make a "bs.EndEdit()" before doing the da.Update() so the changes are taken.

I hope this helps you.

**Edit2:**

Here is a better viewable code, also I made this with SQLConnection etc. (so some calls maybe have to be changed) but it is the same with Oracle (Did that some time ago):

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable"; 
DataSet ds;  
OracleConnection conn;
OracleDataAdapter da; 
BindingSource bs;
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();

private void GetDataAndFillDataGridView()
{
    conn = new OracleConnection(conn_string);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(Query, conn);
    da.Fill(ds, "Tablename");
    bs = new BindingSource(ds, "Tablename");
    dgv.DataSource = bs;
}

private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bs.EndEdit();

    OracleCommandBuilder ocb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
    da.UpdateCommand = ocb.GetUpdateCommand(true);
    da.InsertCommand = ocb.GetInsertCommand(true);
    da.DeleteCommand = ocb.GetDeleteCommand(true);

    da.Update(ds, "Tablename");
}
```

Comment: No, that isn't a case, still same error, and all my DB columns allows nulls -  except first (ID). What do you mean by Databinding ? As you see I exclude some rows from DataGridView and only those rows need to be inserted into some table. Can you post some link to try It out ?

Comment: I've edited question, It was a mistake, I receive error at **da.Fill()**, not da.Update(), sorry for that....

Comment: @Lucy82 I looked a bit better at your question, I got it a bit wrong, but if I understand it right (you want to save changed data back to the DataBase and you work with a DataGridView) then the Databinding is the THING for you. I edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for detailed answer. But you probably still didn't fully understand me so I'll try to elaborate first. As my first sentences in question says, I'm not trying to update my DataGridView, but fetch some rows from It and insert only those specific rows to target table in my DB, which is not same as DataGrid source table.

Comment: That Is why I included loop of my DataGridView rows and created a new DataTable with desired data. It's just a part with da.Fill() that is not working, to get Update working. Beside that, DataGridView is allready binded to BindingSource. But I'm not updating DataGridView or It's underlying data, because that is just a view from DB, and table that needs records to insert holds different data.

Comment: so basically my code needs to know which rows from DataGridView user has selected, then construct proper Datatable from those rows for an insert to a different table . I solved this by a loop and sending each row values directly to desired table, but that is slower than If I would just update dataAdapter to insert everything in same time.

Comment: @Lucy82 Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks, but once again - I'm not updating,inserting or deleting DatagridView data. It only contains a single value in each selected row that needs to be inserted into completely different table. So creating a NEW Datatable is a MUST, and to fill It, I MUST loop Datagridview rows. And after that, and only after that DataAdapter comes in code - but as mentioned in question I can't fill It with that new Datatable. If I could then I would be able to update that completely different table.

Comment: @Lucy82 In the link I posted is a description on how to insert data from a DataTable to a Oracle-Database with a OracleDataAdapter (like in your code). The other thing is, if you would do it with a "dummy"-Table via DataSet/DataAdapter (The Data don't have to be displayed, SELECT an empty Table or whatever) you could generate all the querys with a CommandBuilder and do the DataBase communication fully automated. Your DataAdapter has to know which table etc. anyway. (Load empty Table to DataSet, Add SelectedRows to empty Table, Update "empty Table" with DataAdapter). Just as a suggestion...

Comment: now we are on same spot. I figured out that only problem was to set a SelectCommand to DataAdapter, so that It creates structure. That fixed all my problems, only change was to fill "empty" datatable after calling **da.Fill(dt)**. I'm accepting your answer, so thanks for all your effort !

Comment: @Lucy82 I'm happy, that I could help you and that it finally worked out for you.